# Python Multiprocessing and storing data

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing

I've seen many example doing almost want I'm trying to do but not quite what I need. I have embarrassingly parallel code I'm trying to speed up. The jist of what I'm trying to do is below:

```
t=11
for k in range(100):
    for i in range(10000):
        for j in range(10000):
            s=t*i
    x[k] = s
    y[k] = s+3
```

Okay, so I know most of what I need to do to multithread the topmost loop of 100 repeats:

```
import multiprocessing  

def parAttempt(t):
    for i in range(10000):
        for j in range(10000):
            s=t*i
    x[k] = s
    y[k] = s+3

if __name__ == '__main__'

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
    pool.map(parAttempt, range(100))
```

Which I think the above is mostly right. However, I'm not sure how to do two things. First, how do I appropriately send it both t and the fact that I want to execute it 100 times. And 2nd, how do I store x[k] and y[k] for the 100 repeats I'm trying to do? Is it simply something like:

```
x[k], y[k] = pool.map(parAttempt, range(100))
```

Which can't be right, because k is undefined in the code at that point.

Comment: What are `x` and `y` ? Also - could you describe the "bigger picture" here... sometimes multiprocessing is a waste of time/impractical/results in longer code for no speed up/potential slow down... etc... when other solutions are available.

Comment: Well in my code x is a 1-D numpy array that is storing calculated values and y is a 2-D numpy array.

I'm doing between 100 and 10000 replicate simulations none of which depend on each other. Multithreading should give a linear speed up, I'm just far more familiar with matlab which isn't a choice here for many reasons.

Comment: Something with your example is obviously wrong. As written, your code isn't even using the inner loop or variabe `j`.